# Overwriting tags in neo4j instead of duplicating

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two type of nodes: Persons and Tags. I want to tag my Persons with Tags, but it can happen multiple times.

A way to tag a person with Cypher:

```
CREATE (p1:Person { name : 'Alex'})
CREATE (t1:Tag{ tagId: 't1'})
CREATE 
  (p1)-[:TAGGED]->(t1)
```

However, if I execute this again, then it will create two new persons and tags and connect them. I want to be able to override existing relationships and not create new users or tags if they are already there. What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://www.neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#query-merge) instead `create`:

```
MERGE (p1:Person { name : 'Alex'})
MERGE (t1:Tag{ tagId: 't1'})
MERGE (p1)-[:TAGGED]->(t1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works, but sometimes I see two relationships being added and two tags created with the same name?

Comment: Create a uniqueness constraint on :Person(name) and on :Tag(tagId).

Comment: @NicoleWhite How would you do that?